# Show that $\limsup |s_n|=0$ iff $\lim s_n=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

First suppose $\lim s_n = 0$. then from the definition we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>N$ we have,
\begin{align*}
|s_n-0| = |s_n|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
It follows then that for $\epsilon$, $N$, and $n$ as before we have,
\begin{align*}
|s_n| = ||s_n|-0|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
So $\lim |s_n|=0$. It follows from a theorem discussed in class that $\limsup|s_n|=\lim|s_n|=0$.

Now conversely suppose that $\limsup |s_n| = 0$. We know that,
\begin{align*}
\liminf|s_n|\le\limsup|s_n| = 0.
\end{align*}
However $|s_n|\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So it follows that $\liminf|s_n|=0$.  Since $\liminf|s_n|=\limsup|s_n|=0$ it follows that $\lim|s_n|=0$. Now since $\lim|s_n|=0$, we know that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n>N$ we have,
\begin{align*}
||s_n|-0|=|s_n|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Which implies that for $\epsilon$, $N$, and $n$ as above we have 
\begin{align*}
|s_n-0|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence $\lim s_n=0$ as needed.

indent Therefore $\limsup |s_n| = 0$ if and only if $\lim s_n=0$. **Q.E.D.**

Is this proof correct, if not can I get a hint as to whats wrong with it.

Comment: This proof is fine, is there something in particular that bothers you about your proof?

Comment: I had been stuck on the second half for a bit and then that idea came to me and it just seemed to simple. So I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, your proof is correct. You can sumarize it as follows: **First claim** $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}|s_n|=0$. **Second claim** $\lim_{n\to\infty}|s_n|=0$ if and only if $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|s_n|=0$. As you can see, the second claim is something we already knew. The core of your proof was justifying the first claim.