Help in showing that $\limsup|s_n|=0$ implies that $|s_n| \to 0$
Given $\limsup|s_n| = 0 $, we want to show that $|s_n| \to 0$. I define $v_N=\sup \{|s_n| : n > N\}$
Given $\varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N $ such that $\forall n > N $ $v_N < \varepsilon$. Then,
$$\sup \{|s_n| :  n > N \} <\varepsilon $$
$$|s_n| < \varepsilon\ \forall n > N $$
And this implies $|s_n| \to 0$
I am not entirely sure about 4th and 5th steps. Can you help?

This is correct together with the fact that $0\leq |s_n|$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568558/show-that-limsup-s-n-0-iff-lim-s-n-0

@Yathi i know other method you posted but i wanted to do like this

Can you explain what you know already about limit supermum?

@Yathi highest value that sequence is taking or getting close to after a large stage i.e large value of N

Okay, let us put it like this: the supermum of the set of all limits of the subsequences of the given sequence(assume it to be $|s_n|$. This supermum is $0$. Now, from this can you deduce step 4?

@Yathi This set of all limits is just singleton set. because it cannot have negative value.

Exactly. First note that sequence is bounded. Secondly, can you show that every subsequence must converge and converge to $0$?

@Yathi If Set has only one element then does not it imply that every subsequence converge to that ? or am i missing something ?

If some sub sequence does not converge to $zero$, then for some $\epsilon >0$, infinite number of elements of the subsequence must be greater than $\epsilon$. As the sequence is bounded, those elements greater than $\epsilon$ must have a limit which turns out to be non-zero element in the set of subsequential limits which imlplies supermum can not be zero. A contradiction. Hence, every subsequence converges to $0$. In fact, you could have applied this contradiction argument to the whole sequence itself assuming that it doesn't converge to $0$. You would then directly arrive at your setp 4.

@Yathi  i see. Thanks. "those elements greater than ϵ must have a limit". This part is bit unclear

That is by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem -"Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence"

@Yathi Thanks. Nice prespective. if you post answer i will accept

I am trying to justify your step $4$. By limit supermum, I take it to be the supermum of set of all subsequential limits. As it is $0$, this itself implies that the sequence is bounded.
To show that $|s_n|$ goes to $0$, we make use of the general fact that

if $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n =k$, where $a_n$ is positive for all $n$, then for any $m>k$, there can be only finitely many $n$ such that $a_n\geq m$. In other word, for any $m>k$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we would have $a_n < m$.

The above fact follows easily from Bolzano Weierstrass theorem. If at all there existed infinitely many $n$ such that $a_n \geq m$, as the sequence is bounded, by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence of the original sequence for which the limit is $\geq m > k$ which is contradictory to the fact that $m$ is the upper bound.
Hence, applying this to your case where the limit supermum is $0$, given any $\epsilon >0$, there must be $n$ such that $|s_n| \leq \epsilon$, which would imply that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |s_n| = \lim_{n\to 0} s_n = 0.$$

Hi. Can you help me with this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5008876/confused-if-proof-is-correct-limsup-s-nt-n-infty?noredirect=1#comment10739914_5008876

Let $a_i$ $i\in \mathbb{N}$ be a non-negative sequence.
$b_k:= \sup ${ $a_i : i \ge k$} ;
We have
$0\le a_i \le b_k$ for $i \ge k$.
In particular
$0 \le a_k \le b_k$ and
$0\le lim_{k \rightarrow  \infty} a_k \le lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} b_k=$ $\limsup a_i$ ,
and we are done.
