Confused if proof is correct $ \limsup s_nt_n = +\infty$
Given
$ \limsup s_n =  + \infty $ and $ \liminf t_n > 0$
To prove $$ \limsup s_nt_n = +\infty$$
There exists $s_{n_k}$ such that $ \lim s_{n_k} = +\infty $. Also we have $ \lim t_{n_k} = \liminf t_n $.
$$\lim s_{n_k}t_{n_k} = +\infty $$
Since $\limsup s_nt_n$ is largest all limits of subsequences $s_nt_n$.
So $\limsup s_nt_n = +\infty $
Unsure about last part. Can you guide ? Thanks

We can't say that $\lim t_{n_k} = \liminf t_n$ (we don't know how the $n_k$'s we choose work with $t_n$), but we can say something like: eventually $t_{n_k} \geq (\liminf t_n)/2$ (by definition of $\liminf$), and this is plenty information to see that $s_{n_k} t_{n_k} \to \infty$, because $s_{n_k} t_{n_k} \geq s_{n_k} (\liminf t_n) / 2$ and $(\liminf t_n) / 2$ is positive, so all that goes to infinity.

Hint : choose a subsequence and then a subsubsequence.

@RickDoesMath first line of your comment is not clear.

Because $s_{n_k}$ goes to infinity and other sequence is just a positive limit

$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n=+\infty$, implies, the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is unbounded above and had a subsequence diverging to $+\infty$. Let it be $\{s_{n_k}\}$. Without loss of generality, you may assume that $s_{n_k}>0$ for each $k$ (if not, you can construct such a subsequence with only positive terms).
It is given that $\liminf_{n\to \infty} t_n=\alpha >0$. This, implies, given any $\epsilon$, with $0<\epsilon <\alpha$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $t_n > \epsilon$ (if not, then we can construct a subsequence with limit less than $\alpha$, a contradiction).
Now, let $\{t_{n_k}s_{n_k}\}$ be the subsequence of $\{t_ns_n\}$. Clearly, for all $k$ such that $n_k\geq N$, $t_{n_k}\geq \epsilon >0$. Thus, for all $k$ with $n_k\geq N$, we have
$$t_{n_k}s_{n_k} \geq \epsilon s_{n_k}\to \infty.$$
Thus $\limsup_{n\to \infty} t_ns_n = \infty$.
Note: Instead of this, you could have also shown (very easily) that $\{t_ns_n\}$ is bunbounded above. I leave it to you.

Thanks. i am not entirely sure where my proof is wrong

You haven't justified why $\lim s_{n_k}t_{n_k}$ is $\infty$. If it is done, yours is perfectly alright.

one sequence goes to infinity, other goes to some positive real. product goes to infinity

I think i got it. the error is my part that some of terms of sequence may be 0. hence product may not be infinity

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5008822/doubt-in-last-step-of-proof-limsupks-n-infty
